# simple statistical test for longitudinal ordinal data

Tags: panel-data, ordinal-data

New researcher here. What statistical test do I use to compare scores (on the general self efficacy scale) over time (12 times total including pre-test) to test a single intervention? It's a simple study with a small sample (8 people) and no control group.

Comment: (I don't see a need for a downvote here.)

Comment: What do you want to test? Do you have a single baseline (before) measure & then 11 subsequent measures? Do you just want to see if they scores improve from baseline?

Comment: @kerri would you describe briefly self efficacy scale and type of question items and response scale ?